# Facebook PHP SDK getSession return NULL

Tags: php, facebook, api, sdk, null

```
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookCanvasLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\Entities\AccessToken;

FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($client_id,$client_secret);

$helper = new FacebookCanvasLoginHelper();

try {
    $session = $helper->getSession();
} catch (FacebookRequestException $ex) {
    echo $ex->getMessage();
} catch (\Exception $ex) {
    echo $ex->getMessage();
}

    var_dump($session); exit;
```

Why this code returns me normal session in index.php, but on other pages  returns me NULL ??